# Express the limit as a definite integral on the given interval [Difficulty Interpreting Question]

Tags: definite-integrals

[image]

I understand that they want the integral as an answer, but how would I go about getting this.

Sorry this is all just very new to me and i just want to grasp the concepts :)

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/DefnofDefiniteIntegral.aspx). Pay particular attention to the blue box near the top of the page. See if that helps. :)